# What would be the correct way to create a Firebase admin UI ? How to Sign In as admin account using Firebase in AngularJS app?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, firebase, angularfire

What would be the correct way to create a Firebase admin UI where admin can manage and access Firebase database?

Right now I am trying to implement admin UI for my Angular app using Firebase Admin SDK on another node.js app, I am stuck at how to Authenticate as admin and then grant database access. Or would it be better to create a route for admin in AngularJS site itself?